# excited about; excited at

Tags: vocabulary

> (1) The children were excited about opening their presents.
>   (2) I'm really excited at the prospect of working abroad.
>   (Both are from [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/excited))

The adjective, *excited*, has different complements, *about* and *at* complements. Can these be interchangeable, without nuance change?
Interestingly, OALD’s [Korean version](http://endic.naver.com/enkrEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=97e39aeb94034618b00d0afe02bf3426&query=excited) has slightly different interpretations because of the two propositions: (about -> 느라; at -> 에)
(1) The children were excited by going through the activity of opening their presents.([느라](http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000054761&q=-%EB%8A%90%EB%9D%BC))
(2) I’m very excited is caused by the prospect of working abroad.([에](http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000177759&q=%EC%97%90))
What’s the difference between the two complemtns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrases that can follow "about" and "at" when used with "excited" (in the sense of eagerly looking forward to something) are different. The object of "about" can be a gerund or a noun, whereas "at" cannot take a gerund there, only a noun.

I'm excited about seeing friends over the holiday.

I'm excited at the thought of seeing friends over the holiday.

*I'm excited at seeing friends over the holiday.  [ungrammatical]

A person can be "good at snowboarding", but not "excited at snowboarding".

Comment: ‘Excited at’ couldn’t take gerunds seems not to be matched with COCA’s examples:
“People are excited at having you back”,  “He was excited at being a recording artist”, “At one point, Jerry, excited at having his monotonous evening livened up a little, dashed toward Linda.”, “excited at getting to play at being bigshots for the day”, “Excited at being with Steve”, “excited at his selling fantasies”

Comment: I would not use "at" in those situations, but would follow the example you cited in the question, "excited at the *prospect* of working ..."

Comment: Or "excited to have", "excited to be", "excited to get".  I see more than a few examples of "excited at seeing", for example, but they sound "off" to my ear.

Comment: ngram shows a significant disparity between `(excited to _VERB_),(excited at _VERB_)` for English 1900-2000; and the disparity is significantly greater with American English than with British English, though both greatly favor "excited *to* {verb}".

Comment: COCA shows the same huge disparity in the preference for "excited *to* {verb}" versus "excited *at* {verb}". Search: `excited at *.[v]` versus `excited to *.[v]`